# how to do token pasting for the function call?

Tags: c++

I have a following line in my code .

```
QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::systemBus();

or 

QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
```

I want to define the macro in the makefile, that will enable either system bus or session bus.
However, I want to do the token pasting, something like that.

In the makefile

```
if($(SYSTEM),Y)

    #define DBUS systemBus

endif
```

So, In the .c file -

I want to do the following.

```
  QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::##DBUS();
```

How can I do so? I get the error when I am trying to do the string concatenation.

Comment: Which C compiler supports the `::` scope operator from C++?

Comment: Isn't `#define` in the `makefile` a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token pasting `##` can only be used inside the replacement text of a macro definition.  It cannot be used outside a macro definition.

But there's no need for it anyway; you can simply write in the C code:

```
#ifndef DBUS
#define DBUS sessionBus
#endif

QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::DBUS();
```

And then with the `makefile`, arrange to have the C compiler invoked with:

```
-DDBUS=systemBus
```

when required.  Or you can have the `makefile` always specify one of `sessionBus` or `systemBus`, but it is still a good idea to have the default set in the code (or in a header used by the code).